# SSH jumping with aliases and "-F"

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a server in a private subnet to which I want to connect via a machine that faces the Internet. There are some tutorials for this. I used this one: https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/

The problem with it is that it assumes I can edit the `~/.ssh/config` file. If I am however running code on CI, I would rather use the config file shipped in my repository and use `-F` switch. In this case the above strategy stops working as the `ssh` command used as `ProxyCommand` doesn't load the the same configuration file and doesn't know the aliases. What I did was:

```
Host ansible                                                                    
  User ubuntu                                                                   
  Hostname xxx.compute.amazonaws.com                  

Host app                                                                        
  User ubuntu                                                                   
  Hostname 10.0.2.40                                                            
  ProxyCommand ssh -F test-ssh.cfg -W %h:%p ansible
```

This works but is a little dirty, as I need to put the name of the file into the file itself and it would break if someone changes the filename. So my question is: is there a cleaner way to create a configuration file with aliases and `ProxyCommand` that could be used with `-F`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this SuperUser entry](https://superuser.com/questions/247564/is-there-a-way-for-one-ssh-config-file-to-include-another-one), from version 7.3p1, there is an `Include` directive, so you can create a config file which includes your "regular" config, but has all the `ProxyCommand` entries. This way, if you specify that file, the proxying connections will work, if you omit the `-F` switch, the default config will be read, like this:

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host ansible
  User ubuntu
  Hostname xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
```

`~/.ssh/proxyconfig`:

```
Include config

Host app
  User ubuntu
  Hostname 10.0.2.40
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p ansible
```

If you have configs like above, you can use

```
ssh -F proxyconfig app
```

to reach the "app" server.

If you can't install the aformentioned version to your client computer, you can specify the `ProxyCommand` in the command line, without needing a separate config file, like this:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p ansible' app
```

Since it is a bit uncomfortable to write the whole command every time, you might want to make an alias to the command, or - if you want to access more computers by proxy - a function, like this:

```
function proxyssh {
    # The first argument is the 'stepping stone',
    # the second is the target to ssh into
    ssh -o proxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p $1" $2
}
```

and use it like

```
proxyssh ansible app
```

Answer (score 6):

For proxy hosts you don't need `ProxyCommand` anymore. There is a new option `ProxyJump`, which does the same without the need of another `ssh` with configuration. It will internally issue the same command, but it will also [pass the `-F` argument if provided](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh.c#L1118):

```
Host ansible                                                                    
  User ubuntu                                                                   
  Hostname xxx.compute.amazonaws.com                  

Host app                                                                        
  User ubuntu                                                                   
  Hostname 10.0.2.40                                                            
  ProxyJump ansible
```

This feature is available since [OpenSSH 7.3](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without editing `~/.ssh/config` by using `ProxyCommand` as a parameter.

From [OpenSSH 5.4](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4) (2010-03-08) there has been "netcat mode":

> - Added a 'netcat mode' to ssh(1): `ssh -W host:port ...` This connects    stdio on the client to a single port forward on the
>     server. This    allows, for example, using ssh as a `ProxyCommand` to
>     route connections    via intermediate servers. bz#1618

So it is possible to:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p firewall" user@10.0.2.40
```

For historical versions, you can use external `nc` (from a [SSH ProxyCommand article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/) by Vivek Gite):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh user@firewall nc 10.0.2.40 22' user@10.0.2.40
```

Where

- `firewall` is the server facing the Internet.
- `10.0.2.40` is the server on the local network.
- netcat (`nc`) is used to set and establish a TCP pipe between the servers on your local network.

Comment: Don't recommend `nc`, when the original command already contains `-W` switch doing the same without requiring any other software installed on the jump host.